# AIR single swf for workers

Tags: multithreading, air, web-worker

Trying to make use of the multithreading technique using workers in Adobe AIR

Its possible to use just 1 swf to contain both main and worker swfs
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS2f73111e7a180bd0-5856a8af1390d64d08c-7fff.html

But I'm having a problem initiating my worker code.
In the following the code past else never fires  'else // entry point for the background worker '

```
if (Worker.current.isPrimordial) 
            { 
                // create a background worker 
                //var bgWorker:Worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(swfBytes); 
                initWorker();

                // ... set up worker communication and start the worker 
            } 
            else // entry point for the background worker 
            {
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Is this a mobile project? Workers for Android are currently included in the 3.9 beta as a beta feature (beta feature on a beta, doesn't sound like they will make it into the full release). iOS cannot use workers at all for the foreseeable future.

Comment: No desktop. I'm still troubleshooting but inconsistent results in getting the single swf solution (with 2 runtimes) working. Need to find out why it works only sometimes.